# I can test this rest service in browser on localhost, but not on the web

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]

    public string GetImageStatusByName(string name)
    {
        panonestEntities context = new panonestEntities();
        var p = context.Panoramas.Where(x => x.ImageName.Equals(name)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (p != null)
        {
            return p.Status;
        }

        return "Analysing data";

    }
```

If I go to http://localhost:1539/Services/getimagestatus.svc/GetImageStatusByName?name=800px-Equirectangular-projection
I get the data returned by the service.

but if I publish my website to http://mydomain/Services/getimagestatus.svc/GetImageStatusByName?name=800px-Equirectangular-projection
I get a 404.

In both cases if I browse to http://mydomain/Services/getimagestatus.svc I can see that the service exists.

My problem is not that I can't go to it in browser, but is the fact that the JQuery

```
function updateStatus() {
            $.get("../../Services/getimagestatus.svc/GetImageStatusByName?name=@ViewBag.showProgressFor",
            function (data) {
                if (data != null) {
                    if (data.d != last) {
                        $('#progressList').append('<li>' + data.d + '</li>');
                    } else {
                        $('#progressdot').append('<b> . </b>');
                    }
                    last = data.d;
                    if (data.d == "Done") {

                        $("#status").hide();
                        $("#result").show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

works only on localhost! When uploaded to server it doesn't work anymore

Comment: 404 is returned by the server because it can't find the resource to serve it. Look elsewhere for your problem.

Comment: Ok, but the resource is on the servcer. My guess is that it has to do with mVC3 routes. But I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Look in your web inspector and see what path it's really trying to load.

My hunch is that prepending your path with `"../../"` is the problem.  The webserver on your localhost probably sees and either handles correctly or discards this directory traversal, where your production server does not.

Instead simply try a single leading slash, which is always relative to the current domain.

```
$.get("/Services/getimagestatus.svc/GetImageStatusByName...", ...)
```

This should work on localhost or your domain.

Comment: this didn't solve the problem. I am hosting the service inside an MVC3 application. I think it has to do with MVC routes